# RTPS vs TCP (Foxy)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a question, why FastDDS uses RTPS even for qos_reliability=reliable instead of use TCP?
What are advantages to use RTPS?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388158/rtps-vs-tcp-(foxy)/) by [Thomas10017](https://answers.ros.org/users/84045/thomas10017/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you need to understand that TCP and RTPS are not exactly the same thing. It's like asking why you would use AC voltage instead of a USB plug.

Go look at the diagrams at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model before continuing to read this...

UDP and and TCP are transport protocols (layer 4 in the OSI model), and RTPS is probably layer 5.

The cool thing with the OSI model is that if you really needed to, you could swap out lower layers as long as they provide the same functionality. For example IPoAC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) swaps out the data link layer with pigeons (yes. you read that right.).

Fastdds includes a few different "transport" methods: UDP, TCP, or Shared memory. UDP transport is compatible with other DDS/RTPS vendors as UDP is specified as part of the RTPS protocol. TCP transport and shared memory transport are not part of the RTPS specification (Though I wish they were..) and therefore not compatible with other DDS/RTPS vendors.

So I think bottom line to answer your question: FastDDS uses UDP unless configured otherwise because that's what the RTPS specification defines.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2021-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas10017](https://answers.ros.org/users/84045/thomas10017/) on 2021-10-08**:
Thank you so much for your very informative answer, I learned a lot.
Have a good day and thank you again!